# Provide NMEA data via mock location provider

Tags: java, android, android-location

I currently have an app that uses a bluetooth gps radio to get coordinates. I provide a mock location provider as well to allow other apps to get location info. The question I have is how do I provided the NMEA data directly to other apps that use the LoationManager.addnmealistener option?

I need to do it myself without using another app like bluetoothgps.

Thanks